# Change Material UI label to white on switch not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm dealing with a material-ui [switch](https://material-ui.com/components/switches/).

From what I understand, the following code should change the label text to be white.

```
const PurpleSwitch = withStyles({
  label: {
    color: "white"
  },
})(Switch);

export default function CustomizedSwitches() {
  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<PurpleSwitch />}
        label="This should be white"
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

But the result is:

[image]

This obviously looks fine on a white background but on dark backgrounds not so much. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Switch API does not have a `label` rule name, you need to style the `FormControlLabel` component ([documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/form-control-label/#css)).

```js
const FormControlLabel = withStyles({
  label: {
    color: "white"
  }
})(MuiFormControlLabel);

export default function CustomizedSwitches() {
  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <FormControlLabel control={<Switch />} label="This should be white" />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```